# Multiple django fields reflects to one db field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

**How to create a model with 2 different fields with the same db_column?**

In my example queue_id and content_type_id are always the same id value. So I don't want to store that information twice in a DB table.

I set a db_column for both fields but got the error
`(models.E007) Field 'content_type' has column name 'queue_id' that is used by another field.`

I added error supression. As result I have an invalid sql code for migration:

```
CREATE TABLE `queue_items_generic` (
`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`object_id` integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`queue_id` integer NOT NULL,
`queue_id` integer NOT NULL);
```

Manual migration patch has helped.

But is there an easier way to do the same stuff? I don't want to patch migrations and supress any errors.

**Here is the reproducing problem code:**

```py
from django.db.models import (
    Model,
    ForeignKey,
    OneToOneField,
    CASCADE,
    PositiveIntegerField,
)
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType



class QueueGeneric(Model):
    content_type = OneToOneField(
        ContentType,
        on_delete = CASCADE,
        primary_key = True,
    )

    last_object_id = PositiveIntegerField(
        default = 0,
    )

    last_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'last_object_id')


class QueueItemsGeneric(Model):
    queue = ForeignKey(
        QueueGeneric,
        db_column = 'queue_id',
        on_delete = CASCADE
    )

    content_type = ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        db_column = 'queue_id',
        on_delete = CASCADE
    )

    object_id = PositiveIntegerField()
    object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

## Update #1

A bit digging into `Fields` topic helps to solve the migration problem.
If we provide the `db_type is None` then it won't produce a new column in DB table.

```py
class ShadowForeignKey(ForeignKey):

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return None

class QueueItemsGeneric(Model):
    queue = ForeignKey(
        QueueGeneric,
        db_column = 'queue_id',
        on_delete = CASCADE
    )

    content_type = ShadowForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        db_column = 'queue_id',
        on_delete = CASCADE
    )

    object_id = PositiveIntegerField()
    object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

It looks OK. Some tests will show how it's a stable solution.

Now I have only a problem with error supression. It seems that the field names check into migrations module. For now I have no idea how to override it nicely.

Comment: I don't really understand why you want two fields.

Comment: What you want isn't supported by Django.

Comment: @daniel-roseman To have an easy access from an item to the queue or to the content type. It depends on bussiness logic of the program. (For example I have a *table1* with `IP - HOSTNAME - OWNER - DESCRIPTION` where IP is PK. I have *AVPO log* with `IP_ID - PARSED_AVPO_RECORD`. I have *WindowsEvent log* with `IP_ID - PARSED_EVENT_RECORD`. And I want to match thats logs to each other. I don't want to use `table1` in my query cause I know that for both logs IP_ID is the same. I want to use a ForeignKey mechanism that is easy to use)

Comment: @dirkgroten I see... But maybe I can override something in a simple way to achive the desired behaviour? Something like a creating a custom ForeignKey with special methods for migration and django checks.

Comment: You can always try to subclass `ForeignKey` and try to remove it from migrations. Look at the source code I would say.